# Why am I getting a outofbounds error?

Tags: java

I keep getting a Exception in thread "main"

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   5     at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)     at
>   hackman.NewClass.startGame(NewClass.java:31)  at
>   hackman.Decipher.main(Decipher.java:65)

```
public NewClass()
{

}

public char[] startGame()
{
    char[] virusB = new char[100];
    String virus;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your message");
    virus = scan.nextLine();
    for(int i=0; i<virusB.length+1; i++)
    {                   
        virusB[i]= virus.charAt(i);
    }  
    virusA = virusB;

    return virusA;             
}
```

Comment: `i < virusB.length + 1` a recipe for disaster. Seriously. You should be asking yourself, why this wouldn't cause an index out of bounds problem.

Comment: You need to check how long `virus` is. And you loop is too long (by 1) for the array, too.

Comment: Why are you copying a String into a `char[]` anyway?

Comment: All I see is a TON of effort trying to fix this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the string `virus` is not long enough:

> ```
>     char[] virusB = new char[100];
>      String virus = scan.nextLine();
>      for(int i=0; i<virusB.length+1; i++)
>      {                   
>      virusB[i]= virus.charAt(i);
> ```

You iterate until the end + 1 of `virusB`, whose length is 100,
and judging by your error message, the length of `virus` is 5.

For example if `scan.nextLine()` returns "hello", this will happen in the loop:

```
virusB[0] = virus.charAt(0);  // 'h'
virusB[1] = virus.charAt(1);  // 'e'
virusB[2] = virus.charAt(2);  // 'l'
virusB[3] = virus.charAt(3);  // 'l'
virusB[4] = virus.charAt(4);  // 'o'
virusB[5] = virus.charAt(5);  // -> boom
// ...
```

You need to fix the loop condition:

1. take into account `virus.length()` too
2. the limit `virusB.length + 1` is also wrong

In other words:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < virus.length() && i < virusB.length; i++) {
     // ...
 }
```

But the best is probably to simplify the whole thing:

```
public char[] startGame() {
     System.out.print("Enter your message");
     return new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().toCharArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your exception is probably due to this line:

```
virusB[i]= virus.charAt(i);
```

`i` can be up to the length of your `virusB` array, or 100 elements. But the string entered by the user could be much smaller than that. Let's say that the user enters 11 characters: your loop could try to access a character past the end of that string, hence your exception

The specific exception suggests that the string entered by the user leading to the exception was only 4 characters.

One way to prevent this is to add a check to your loop termination condition such that you can't run off the end of the `virus` string, something like:

```
for (int i = 0; (i < virusB.length) && (i < virus.length()); i++)
```

Similarly, your existing loop termination condition of `i<virusB.length+1` can also lead to an exception. Arrays are *zero indexed*, so accessing the element at index `virusB.length` is also out of bounds.

Comment: The `i` loop is too long (by 1), too.

Comment: You're right, merge our answers and this will be fully correct!

Comment: @Alex and Thilo you're right but that part of the question was edited out before I could mention that

Comment: @pb2q I hate it when that happens.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you have it's here:

```
virusB[i]= virus.charAt(i);
```

Because if your `virus length` it's less than `100` it will fail (because you make your for loop until `virusB` length).

What I recommend to you it's to change your if condition to the length of your virus instead of your array. Like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<virus.length; i++)
{                   
    virusB[i]= virus.charAt(i);
}
```

With this method you will avoid that the length of your virus will be lower than the length of your array.

**EDIT:** What I mean with my explanation before it's that when you are trying to accessing to a position of the `String` that doesn't exists, it always will crash. For example, if you have the following `String`:

```
String prove = "This is a prove";
```

From your position `16` to `100` it will fail in your statement:

```
virusB[i]= virus.charAt(i);
```

Because the `virus String` don't have enough length to allow the function `charAt` works properly (it will try to access to a position of the `String` that doesn't exists).

I expect it will be helpful for you!

Comment: There is also `String#toCharArray`

Comment: @Thilo Yes, it could be also another option. But there are a lot of ways to go to Rome ;) Just I did it for not to change the logic of the OP.

Comment: Absolutely. It always helps when people explain why they need to go to Rome in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the index `virusB.length[i]+1` in your loop.  Your char array is only 100 characters, and this loop will iterate 100 times, meaning on the last call in the loop it will try to access index 100 which does not exist as arrays index from 0.

Just try `virusB.length[i]`

Comment: Sorry I just put that in their to see if it would fix it, but it doesn't work with just virusB.length @alex